# Using tern_for_vim plugin in HTML files

Tags: vim, tern

I'm trying to set up [tern_for_vim](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim) plugin to have nice autocompletion in JavaScript. While editing ".js" files, "Ctrl+X Ctrl+O" gives nice semantic results, picking up the "backbone.js" and other libraries. However, when I'm editing a JS block inside an HTML file, this doesn't work, I only see the buffer-based standard completion. I can't figure out what's the problem. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the plugin; I hope I have the right one:  https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim

It seems to make a difference only for javascript files.  If you want to use it for html files, you could try one of these (in order of increasing levels of indirection)

```
:setlocal omnifunc=tern#Complete
:call tern#Enable()
:runtime after/ftplugin/javascript_tern.vim
:set ft=html.javascript_tern
:set ft=html.javascript
```

If any of these have the desired effect, then you can set vim up to do the corresponding thing automatically.  Probably simplest (if the middle suggestion works) is to make a copy of javascript_tern.vim in the same directory, and call it html_tern.vim.

Comment: Thanks, man. Copying the file did the trick. However, I still can't make it work with YouCompleteMe, But that's a different story. At least I can start working now