# How to call js completion in html file instead of js file?

Tags: javascript, vim, autocomplete

I had installed tern_for_vim and YouCompleteMe for js completion this way.

1 install node

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install node
```

2 install tern_for_vim

```
$ cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim
```

3 install YouCompleteMe

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
$ ./install.sh --clang-completer --tern-completer
```

4 edit .tern-project

```
vim  .tern-project  
{
    "libs": [
        "browser",
        "underscore",
        "jquery"
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "node": {}
    }
}
```

Now to  vim test.js.
The js completion pop up after inputing `document.` in test.js file.
[image]

Then to vim test.html
No  js completion pop up after inputing `document.` in test.html file.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not officially supported by tern. You can see the response in a closed issue

https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/issues/170

> Because the parsing logic for separating HTML and scripts hasn't been implemented. This could be done as a plugin, if you want to take a shot at it, but it's out of scope for this repository.

But then there is another thread on SO which may help you

[Using tern_for_vim plugin in HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792956/using-tern-for-vim-plugin-in-html-files)

So best is to include your code in the html through a JS file and then edit the JS file. Else look at some other plugin/IDE environment. I would explore the below option as well

https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim#install

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with tern_for_vim and YouCompleteMe for js completion, however you could always use vim's built in omni-func completion.

If you add:

```
filetype on
filetype plugin on
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

to your vimrc file, you can then manually set the filetype of your html file to javascript with `:set filetype=javascript` whilst in vim. 
Following that, when in insert mode, you can then use `<C-x>` followed by `<C-o>` to access javascript language specific omni completion.

The resulting completion menu is then navigable by the standard `<C-p>` for up and `<C-n>` for down hotkeys.

This, along with other bits of built in completion functionality are discussed in a nice [thoughtbot talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TX3kV3TICU).